# Explicit form of a double indexed sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

I wonder if there is a classical way of resolution of the following sequence : 
$$P(m,1):=\frac{2}{m!}, \qquad P(m,n+1) := \frac{2}{m!} + mP(m+1,n). \quad (1)$$
The results I obtained with the first values of $n$ are quite complicated and doesn't give a clear induction pattern...

**Motivation :** I am studying the generalized function $$T_{\frac{\mathrm{sgn}(x)}{x^n}}:= \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}(\mathrm{sgn}(x)\ln(|x|))^{(n)} \quad (2)$$
where the derivation is taken in the sense of the distributions. I don't know if this definition is canonical (it is made up by myself for a specific use), but I was wondering what would be $x^n T_{\frac{\mathrm{sgn(x)}}{x^{n+m}}}$ equal to. I obtained 
$$ x^n T_{\frac{\mathrm{sgn(x)}}{x^{n+m}}} = T_{\frac{\mathrm{sgn(x)}}{x^{m}}}-P(m,n) \delta_0^{(m-1)} \quad (3)$$
where $\delta_0$ is the Dirac distribution and $P$ is defined as in (1).

**Nota:** It is not an homework...Moreover, I can survive with only (3), but if there exists an explicit form, it would be much more satisfying, isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can recursively use the definition to reach

\begin{align}
P(m,n)&=\frac{2}{m!}+\frac{2m}{(m+1)!}+\dots+\frac{2m(m+1)\dots(m+k-1)}{(m+k)!}\\
&\ +m(m+1)\cdots(m+k)P(m+k+1,n-k-1)
\end{align}
and by plugging in $k=n-2$ to be able to use the $P(m,1)$ definition, this eventually leads to
$$
P(m,n)=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{2(m+k-1)!}{(m-1)!(m+k)!}=\frac{2}{(m-1)!}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{m+k} = \frac{2(H_{m+n-1}-H_{m-1})}{(m-1)!}
$$

where $H_n$ is $n$-th [Harmonic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number):
$$
H_n = 1+\frac{1}{2}+\dots+\frac{1}{n}.
$$

Comment: Well done! That's a great method! Just a remark : isn't that \begin{align}
P(m,n)&=\frac{2}{m!}+\frac{2m}{(m+1)!}+\dots+\frac{2m(m+1)\dots(m+k-1)}{(m+k)!}\\
&\ +m(m+1)\cdots(m+k-1)P(m+k,n-k)
\end{align} (instead of  $m(m+1)\cdots(m+k)P(m+k-1,n-k-1)$, for the last line)?

Comment: @Netchaiev It shouldn't be, the $-1$ is there because I have rewritten your definition to $P(m,n) := \frac{2}{m!} + mP(m+1,n-1)$. I can double check with paper later.

Comment: Yes you are right, but it still seems to me that it is $+m(m+1)\cdots(m+k)P(m+k\mathbf{+}1,n-k-1)$. (the case $k=1$ gives for the last term $m(m+1)P(m+2,n-2)$).

Comment: @Netchaiev You are right, fixed.

Comment: Ok! Thank you again for your elegant solution!